# I used `go install golang.org/dl/go1.19@latest` , next my GOROOT has been modify , and I can't modify it

Tags: go

upgrade my go environment

```bash
go install golang.org/dl/go1.19@latest
```

next , run `go run main.go`

[image]

next, I try modify my GOROOT.

[image]

so, terrible!

I only download again golang. next, goimport,gopls some tools install again

I should reinstall `go tools` when I upgrade go environment, I feel headache!

And VS Code need used the `go install go@version`.

Comment: The proper way to update Go is to just update Go by installing the latest version according to https://go.dev/doc/install . The hack you try to do is completely unnecessary and doesn't really do what you think it does. Just follow https://go.dev/doc/install it takes something around 1 minute.

Answer (score 2):

[The instructions](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/dl/go1.19) mention:

> ```
> $ go install golang.org/dl/go1.19@latest
> $ go1.19 download
> ```
>
> And then use the go1.19 command as if it were your normal go command.

That means `go` still refer to your normal legacy Go (1.18)

You should use `go1.19` to test what you just installed.

---

That being said, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781489/i-used-go-install-golang-org-dl-go1-19latest-next-my-goroot-has-been-modify?noredirect=1#comment131978701_74781489), if you goal is to just upgrade Go, using the [regular installer](https://go.dev/doc/install) is preferable.